# How to Mock Object in Jmock? If Object created using new operator

Tags: java, jmock

I have below piece of code in method.

```
AdminServiceProxy proxy=new AdminServiceProxy();
boolean flag=proxy.isAdminFree();
```

How to mock "AdminServiceProxy " using `Jmock`. Since object is getting created using new operator.

Answer (score 0):

You can't.

One possible solution is to create an AdminServiceProxyFactory interface and implementation:

```
public interface AdminServiceProxyFactory {
    public AdminServiceProxy createAdminServiceProxy();
}

public class AdminServiceProxyFactoryImpl {
    public AdminServiceProxy createAdminServiceProxy() {
        return new AdminServiceProxy();
    }
}
```

Then in your class add a setter and private attribute:

```
public class Foo {
    private AdminServiceProxyFactory adminServiceProxyFactory;
    ...
    public void setAdminServiceProxyFactory(AdminServiceProxyFactory factory) {
        adminServiceProxyFactory = factory;
    }

    public myMethod() {
        ...
        AdminServiceProxy proxy=adminServiceProxyFactory.createAdminServiceProxy();
        boolean flag=proxy.isAdminFree();
        ...
    }

}
```

Now you can create a mock AdminServiceProxyFactory and inject it into your class.  You then tell your mock factory to return a mock AdminServiceProxy when it is called.

Comment: Problem is I am not allowed to change the source code. we might have to use Power-mock in such case.   
@JimNicholson Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

jMock does not support the mocking of "future objects" or the mocking of constructors.

Other mocking libraries provide such support. One of them (which I developed) is JMockit, whose syntax was originally inspired by jMock's "Expectations". In this case, we could have:

```
@Test
public void exampleTestThatMocksAFutureObject(@Mocked AdminServiceProxy proxy) {
    new Expectations() {{ proxy.isAdminFree(); result = true; }};

    // Call code under test which instantiates an AdminServiceProxy...
    boolean adminFree = new AdminServiceProxy().isAdminFree();

    assertTrue(adminFree);
}
```